# Flutter Slider, problem with lists, map and elements inside

Tags: flutter

I try to put a Corousel Slider but with a List that is updated automatically in another part of the app.

The documentation for the slider is with static photos. I want to access to the items inside a list and iterate.

```
  var itemss = [];
   for (var e = 0; e < model.listFireforce.length; e++) {
     itemss.add(model.listFireforce[e].image);
   }
  return CarouselSlider(
      height: 350.0,
      items: [ itemss // HERE IS THE PROBLEM !!
        ].map((i) {
        return Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                child: 

                Image.network(
                  i,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ));
          },
        );
      }).toList());
```

i itearate only 1 time, but no for all the items inside. I try forEach() but i have no solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you wrap your `itemss` array in another array and map over that. You may want to try this:

```
return CarouselSlider(
      height: 350.0,
      items: itemss.map((i) {
        return Builder(
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 2.0),
                decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                child: Image.network(
                  i,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ));
          },
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
```